# Mounting secrets with proper access control in kubernetes pods

Tags: container, secrets-management, kubernetes

I am trying to mount a secret in the pod securely. I have created the secrets with `defaultMode: 0400` and `runAsUser:1000`. However when i am trying to access the secret in the container after doing exec in it, the secret file is owned by root. So the user with UID:1000 is not able to access it.

**Pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
containers:
- image: busybox
  command: ["sleep","5000"]
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
  volumeMounts:
  - name: secret-volume
    mountPath: /opt/secretdir
    readOnly: true
volumes:
- name: secret-volume
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
      defaultMode: 0400
```

**Output of ls -l**

`-r--------    1 root     root             8 Jul  5 14:05 mysec`

Why is the file created with root ownership?
What is the secured way to mount secrets in the pod? Please provide an example manifest if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that this is a long standing issue in Kubernetes (GitHub Issue [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81089)). Whilst you *can* change the user of service account token secrets by setting `RunAsUser` at the Pod level (reference [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/projected-volumes/#linux)), you can't set the owner of a general secret.

The workaround, is to set the permissions of the secret to be one that all users **in the container** can read. As, generally, there's only one active user in a container, this often won't be a serious security issue. To do this you set the `defaultMode` in the Volume definition to be something like `0666`.

Comment: Tried adding the SecurityContext to Pod level, still facing the same issue.

Comment: @warrior-oo7 do you have a copy of the updated pod manifest you're applying?

Comment: here is the link to the updated yaml
https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/y2379c208

Comment: @warrior-oo7 thanks! I took more of a look into this, and updated the answer with what I've found :)